# How can i calculate linear interpolation between two numbers using given steps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, interpolation

How can i calculate interpolation between start and stop?

example: interpolation (start, stop, step)

```
interpolation(1, 5, 1) -> [1.0]
interpolation(1, 5, 2) -> [1.0, 5.0]
interpolation(1, 5, 3) -> [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
interpolation(1, 5, 4) -> [1.0, 2.333333333333333, 3.6666666666666665, 5.0]
interpolation(1, 5, 5) -> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
interpolation(5, 1, 5) -> [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that for `step=1` - you need to return `[start]` and for `step=2` - `[start, stop]`?

Comment: I strongly recommend choosing another name for `step`, for instance `num_steps` or just `num`. The name `step` is almost always used to mean "the difference between one element and the next", not "the number of elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.linspace(5, 1, 5)
# array([5., 4., 3., 2., 1.])

np.linspace(1, 5, 4)
# array([1.        , 2.33333333, 3.66666667, 5.        ])
```

or with pure python:

```
def interpolation(start, stop, step):
    if step == 1:
        return [start]
    return [start+(stop-start)/(step-1)*i for i in range(step)]

interpolation(5, 1, 5)
# [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]

interpolation(1, 5, 4)
# [1.0, 2.333333333333333, 3.6666666666666665, 5.0]
```